# Saving user page history and displaying random page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web

I am developing a website were I will have pages with videos on them.

I will have a feature where the website will continuously play through random videos(load random pages after videos finish playing). I want to make sure that the user doesn't get the same videos over and over with the random feature.

So I would like to save the users page history somehow.

Can anyone point me into the right direction on how to implement something like this?

EDIT
I wont be having user registration on this website.

Comment: Never see the same video again? Register users, use DB. Never see the same video in one sitting? Use sessions.

Comment: @Josh I won't have registered users so I guess I would have to use sessions. I have not messed around with sessions before. Could you give me a little more information on how to implement sessions for my purposes?

Comment: Start a session (`session_start()`). Store videos that have already played for the user in a session variable. Before playing a video, check to see if it exists in the user's session. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: @Josh Thanks for the help. I ended up using sessions and it seems to be working wonderfully.

Comment: That's great! We're here if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save the views in the database with a table in the sort of:

user_views (user_id, video_id, last_viewed)

now you need to select a random record from the videos table where the id is not in (SELECT `video_id` FROM `user_views` WHERE `user_id` = _USER_ID_ AND last_viewed > X)

X would be the minimal past time for re-viewing the video in the random videos list

hope this helps

Comment: I'm not planning on having user registration so I won't have a user_id to assign. Would I have to use sessions in that case?

Comment: yup, use sessions. in that case you don't need the database, just save a list of video ids in the session

Comment: thanks ended up using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is an example algorthm :

1) Set a unique id for your user but it must be encrypted. (for example : MD5(USER_ID.USER_NAME.REGISTERATION_DATE))

2) Send a cookie to user which containing this unique id

3) Create a new database table (for example *history*) . *history* will has 2 columns . **ID** and **videos** .

4) WHen a user watch a video check him / her unique ID from cookie, and then add new video's ID  to *history*'s videos column.

I'm storing an encrypted ID because of security. If we encrypt it , user can't modify this. If we don't encryt if, user can suggest our cookie's pattern (i mean `USER_ID.USER_NAME.REGISTERATION_DATE`) and modify it. So he can reach another user's history.

Comment: I won't be having user registration on this application.

Comment: OK don't register user. Doesn't matter. Store another thing about user. FOr example `MD5(USER_ID)` . Other everything is same.